# Backend/Frontend CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, frontend, cakephp-3.0, backend

I made an application with cakephp, using the --prefix command to create with backend. The case is that I have done the authentication for the backoffice part, and now the frontend can not be accessed if it is not registered. What could be the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by front-end can't be accessed ? Do you mean you need some function make accessible without login ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
In the beforefilter function if I add checkAuthIn controller initialize, it only asks me to login to the backoffice and not to the front office, but this makes it possible to access any part without being logged in. If I do not put this always ask for login for the frontend.